# MSB4126 The specified solution configuration "Release2018, Release2019|Any CPU" is invalid

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Devops Pipeline with a solution that has multiple configurations - Release2018, Release2019, Release2020, Release2021.

If I build them separately then each of them builds properly, but if I try to follow the documentation to build multiple configurations in parallel then I am getting this error:

***MSB4126 The specified solution configuration "Release2018, Release2019|Any CPU" is invalid.***

Original Error:

```
##[error]d:\a\1\s\Product\Source\BIMrxAddinTemplate.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration **"Release2018, Release2019|Any CPU"** is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.
     1>Project "d:\a\1\s\Product\Source\BIMrxAddinTemplate.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
     1>d:\a\1\s\Product\Source\BIMrxAddinTemplate.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release2018, Release2019|Any CPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration. [d:\a\1\s\Product\Source\BIMrxAddinTemplate.sln]
     1>Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\Product\Source\BIMrxAddinTemplate.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

The setup is done exactly as described at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Peter, is there any update for this issue? Please check if Jane's answer helps to resolve your issue, you can [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) if it's helpful. So that members with similar error can benefit from the useful info~

Answer (score 0):

> MSB4126 The specified solution configuration "Release2018, Release2019|Any CPU" is invalid.

I have successfully reproduced a similar error to yours.

[image]

There are multiple reasons leading to this error. You can check the following sections:

1. Edit pipeline and go to the agent job of the tasks. Select Multi-configuration and set the value of Multipliers to `BuildConfiguration`.

[image]

2. In build task, set the value of Configuration to `$(BuildConfiguration)`.

[image]

3. Go to Variables. Create the value `BuildConfiguration` and set its value to `Release2018, Release2019, Release2020, Release2021`. Select the 'Settable at queue time' checkbox.

[image]

**Update:**

If you are using YAML pipeline:

```
jobs:
- job: Test
  strategy:
    maxParallel: 2
    matrix: 
      Debug:
        BuildConfiguration: debug
      Release:
        BuildConfiguration: release
  steps:
  ...
```

And you don't need to add 'BuildConfiguration' in variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately my pipeline is a Yaml pipeline that has no configuration for the Agent Job.

Still, I should be able to add multiple configuration values, as described at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops